# Anyway to know when a project finished in Apache Storm?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a question about Apache Storm. My current application has multiple projects which run continuously to update latest data from other services. When a project completed, it will be started again after a modifiable interval to update data.

We're moving to Apache Storm and Kafka for new version. Our design is putting project metadata into Kafka then Storm will read from Kafka and start projects. But since we have many Bolts to process data then we haven't found out any solution to indicate when a project completed updating data to update its status so a scheduler can know that this project was done for a while then putting it to Kafka again after specific interval.

So my question is for a design like this, is there anyway to handle project status, to know when a project finished in Storm? Thank u in advance

Comment: When you say *project*, do you mean *tuple*? So your question becomes how to know when the topology successfully processed a tuple emitted by a spout?

Comment: Nope, project here is like an agent, for example: we have to get data from a profile, we create a project of Twitter with that username, this process can be divided to multiple bolts to crawl tweets, followings, followers... So we want to know when all is done to put this project status to "completed" to let a scheduler know when to start updating data again

Comment: Eh if you're building a crawler that starts at a regular interval then I don't think Storm is the right choice here.